# How to write a query using COUNT, GROUP BY, ORDER BY in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to write a query in sequelize ORM using GROUP BY, ORDER BY, COUNT.

Here is my SQL query :

```sql
SELECT COUNT(1),
       bucket_name,
       clusterId
FROM aidc_tenoco.output_table
WHERE clusterId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY clusterId
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
LIMIT 0,
      1
```

I want to write in sequelize please help me out.

Answer (score 9):

#### Code

```js
const Op = require("sequelize").Op;
const sequelize = require("../models").sequelize;

models.OutputTable.findOne({
    where: {
      clusterId: {
        [Op.ne]: null,
      },
    },
    attributes: ["bucket_name", "clusterId", [sequelize.fn("COUNT", "1"), "CountedValue"]],
    group: ["clusterId"],
    order: [[sequelize.col("CountedValue"), "DESC"]],
});
```

#### Explanation

Use the docs - [Querying](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html)
It is pretty straight forward.

The `findOne` method limits your query to 1. The attribute clause selects the `column_names`. Know that sequelize won't identify your `CountedValue` column hence `order` it using `sequelize.col(columnAlias)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for response but not getting exact result

Comment: Do tell what does the log show when you execute the above query. At my end, the above query generates the exact query as you asked.